# Adjust width of inline buttons automatically based on parent width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have 3 buttons that are inline. I'm having issues in how to style these buttons so the width is automatically calculated to take the width of the parent div.  For example, if the parent div is 1000px, I'd like the width of the inline buttons to be 1000/3 - a set margin to space these buttons. So those need to be taken into account which will be fixed.  Catch is, the first and last element should not have a left margin and right margin respectively. This way I can dynamically add buttons and the styling should take care of the width. Hope that helps?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyej20nk/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="width: 1000px;border: 1px solid #999;">
  <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
    <a href="1" class="btn-lg btn-default">My Button</a>
    <a href="2" class="btn-lg btn-default">My Button2</a>
    <a href="3" class="btn-lg btn-default">My Button3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The number of buttons is variable?

Comment: @Imgonzalves Yes. I have a dynamic page and based on permissions only certain buttons show up. :)

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fluid-width-variable-item-navigation-css/. Also you can check the result in this CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/vFsAy/.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table as so:

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tbody style="width:inherit;">
    <tr>
      <td>Left</td>
      <td>Centre</td>
      <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then add as many `<td>` elements as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with **bootstrap**, you have to understand the **grid system**. There is `col-xs-...`, `col-sm-...`, `col-md-...`, `col-lg-...` to handle the column width. Therefore don't set a width. Read [bootstrap grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to understand the basics. A whole width of the screen has in **total 12 columns**. For example col-xs-12 in smaller displays fills the whole width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-..."></div>
    <div class="col-..."></div>
    <div class="col-..."></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row myButtons">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">   
        <a href="1" class="btn btn-lg">My Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">   
        <a href="1" class="btn btn-lg">My Button2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">   
        <a href="1" class="btn btn-lg">My Button3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here in all device sizes *every part* has 4 columns. In total 12. (Set, for example **every** `cols-xs-4` to `col-xs-12` and resize the screen to see what happens!). **That's how** **bootstrap** **work**.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Amwiom/s9zht9bp/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are ignoring bootstrap standards, and wanting to custom style this.

try

```
.row {
    /*width: 1000px;*/
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.row .row {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin 0 -10px; /*offset the left and right gutter*/
}

.btn-default {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px; /*example margin*/
    padding: 30px;/*example padding */
    /*width: 30%;*/ /*fall back if needed*/
    width: Calc((100% / 3) - 20px); /*minus 2 x margin*/

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luongatoolz/Lyej20nk/5/)

Answer (score 1):

KingKongFrog. Hi again. When you set a width to a fixed value like 1000px you lose the ability to be responsive. Try to use percentage. When using Bootstrap the xs starts around 700px, if you have say 3 buttons side by side you can run into problems fitting them across a small screen like 320px.
So you need to take over control from bootstrap css a little to do want you want to do.
I have added some of the bootstrap classes and also added some more custom classes to help show what you may need to do here.
Using  `@media (max-width: 320px)`  is the main width that you may need to control like reducing the size of the buttons/fonts etc. And if using any `col-xs-offset-X` when it shown on a screen size within 320px you will need to reset these to zero left etc.

Custom css that you want/need to over ride Bootstrap needs to be placed below bootstrap in the page.

Have a look at the **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c31qcm5c/)** and try resizing it.

Here is a **[full screen fiddle view](https://jsfiddle.net/c31qcm5c/embedded/result/)** that's easy for resizing.

```
<br>
<div class="container bg-info">
 <br>   
<div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning"> 
<br>    
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 
col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-2 
col-xxs-pull-1">   
<a href="1" class="btn btn-sm bg-primary btn-size">My Button1</a>
 </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3
col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-0
.col-xxs-offset-1">   
<a href="1" class="btn bg-primary btn-size">My Button2</a>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3
col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-0
col-xxs-push-1">   
<a href="1" class="btn bg-primary btn-size">My Button3</a>
</div>
<br><br>    
</div> 
<br>     
</div>
```